# Что значит установить пакет глобально?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Всех приветствую! Прошу помощи у сообщества, не откажите и объясните по простому, что значит установить пакет глобально? Например, `npm install -g webpack`?

Comment: Пакет установится не в папку проекта. Это нужно для различных cli - утилит, например для создания проекта (create-react-app, vue-cli)

Comment: @SultanovShamil, что-то ты как-то странно объяснил...

Answer (score 6):

Установить глобально - это указать при установке флаг `-g`. После этого пакет поставится в определённую папку (в Windows - специфичную для пользователя, в Linux - для всей системы) и станет доступен из командной строки.

Обращаю внимание, что пакет оказывается специфичен для компьютера, а не для проекта, соответственно если передаётся некоторый код, рассчитывающий на глобально установленные модули, то их придётся ставить самостоятельно. Кроме того, нельзя использовать одновременно разные версии глобально установленных модулей.

Поэтому, если речь идёт о разработке, то глобальную установку обычно не используют. Вместо неё модуль устанавливается как зависимость, а в секции `scripts` файла `packadge.json` прописывается команда для его запуска через npm.

Глобально имеет смысл устанавливать утилитные пакеты, которые нужны лично тебе для каких-то целей, например, `http-server`, если ты хочешь показать другу статический сайтик.

Comment: Вот, кстати, в 4 версии webpack, webpack-cli устанавливать глобально?